# RDD sent to RED address

Tags: wallet

I wanted to transfer my my RDD coins from Bittrex account to my cryptsy account. I mistakenly sent the RDD coins to A RED generated address on my Criptsy account.

Pls how is it possible to recover my coins? The techs at Cryptsy have been on it for 2 weeks now and have been very helpful in keeping me updated.

I would appreciated some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You have the first part right. REDD and RDD use the same pub/priv encoding scheme. Therefore we can simply export the privkey of his RED deposit address and import it into the REDD wallet. Then rescan. This does take time and we are working on ways to automate this. (It happens quite often ) -Mullick "Technical Support Manager"

Comment: Fantastic. Luckily the pubkey scheme is the same and you guys are helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If REDD & RED are using the same set of public keys (ie each public key address is valid for both coins' Blockchains) then the **only way** to retrieve coins from a public address is if:

1. You owns the private key
2. Someone else (eg Cryptsy) owns the private key

Since 1 is false, you'd need to hope 2 is true. The odds of Cryptsy having a subset of REDD keys overlapping RED keys is as likely as creating a Bitcoin address and finding coins in it.

Sorry, your coins are gone.